# undefined value single checkbox javascript to another page

Tags: php, javascript, facebox

i have two page, the first page is index.php i also using facebox framework in it. the second page is addevent.php i've tried in many ways to catch the value of single checkbox in addevent.php and passing it to index.php. but it didn't show the value. so is there someting wrong with my code ? what i'm miss ? any help would be appreciate..

index.php

```
echo ">".$check=$_REQUEST['check'];
echo "check[0]: ".$check[0]; 
<head>
<script src="inc/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="inc/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
<a href="addevent.php" rel="facebox" >link</a> 
</body>
```

addevent.php

```
<head>
<script src="inc/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="inc/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function AddEventAgenda(){

//--- i've tried this method & firebug said:document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0] is undefined----

    var elemLength = document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.length;
    if (elemLength==undefined) {
    elemLength=1;
    if (document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.checked) {
        // we know the one and only is checked
        var check = "&check[0]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0].value;
    }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i<elemLength; i++) {
            if (eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].checked) {
        var check = "&check["+i+"]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].value + check;
            }
        }
    }

//--- also this one same firebug said:document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0] is undefined---

    var len = document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.length;
    if(len == undefined) len = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var check = "&check["+i+"]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].value + check;
    }


//--- and this one same firebug said:document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0] is undefined---

    var formNodes  = document.eventAgendaForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<formNodes.length;i++) {
    /* do something with the name/value/id or checked-state of formNodes[i] */
    if(document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].checked){
    var check = "&check["+i+"]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].value + check;
    }
}

//--- and this one same firebug said:document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0] is undefined---

if (typeof document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.length === 'undefined') {
   /*then there is just one checkbox with the name 'user' no array*/
        if (document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.checked == true )
                            {
                                var check = "&check[0]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[0].value;
                            }   
    }else{
  /*then there is several checkboxs with the name 'user' making an array*/
        for(var i = 0, max = document.eventAgendaForm.checkName.length; i < max; i++){
            if (document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].checked == true )
                            {
                                var check = "&check["+i+"]=" + document.eventAgendaForm.checkName[i].value + check;
                            }
        }
    }

//-----------------------------------------------
    window.location="index.php?tes=1" + check; // display the result
    $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
}

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
// i don't know if these code have connection with checkbox or not? 
        function addLoadEvent(func) {
            var oldonload = window.onload;

            if (typeof window.onload != "function") {
                window.onload = func;
            } else {
                window.onload = function () {
                    oldonload();
                    func();
                }
            }
        }

        addLoadEvent(function () {
            initChecklist();
        });
        function initChecklist() {
            if (document.all && document.getElementById) {
                // Get all unordered lists
                var lists = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

                for (i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                    var theList = lists[i];

                    // Only work with those having the class "checklist"
                    if (theList.className.indexOf("checklist") > -1) {
                        var labels = theList.getElementsByTagName("label");

                        // Assign event handlers to labels within
                        for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++) {
                            var theLabel = labels[j];
                            theLabel.onmouseover = function() { this.className += " hover"; };
                            theLabel.onmouseout = function() { this.className = this.className.replace(" hover", ""); };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>


</head>

<form name="eventAgendaForm" id="eventAgendaForm" >
<ul class="checklist cl3">
<li ><label for="c1">
<input id="checkId" name="checkName" value="1" type="checkbox" >
</label></li></ul>
<input class="tombol" type="button" name="Add" value="Add" onclick="AddEventAgenda()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use jQuery if you are including jQuery library?

```
  var checkbox_val=jQuery("#CHECKBOX_ID_HERE").val();//gets you the value regardless if checked or not
  var checkbox_val=jQuery("#CHECKBOX_ID_HERE").attr("checked"); //returns checked status
```

or

```
var global_variable=""; //should be initialized outside any function
jQuery("#FORM_ID_HERE").children(":input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).attr("checked"))global_variable+="&"+jQuery(this).attr("name")+"="+jQuery(this).val();
});
```

this is just a suggestion to start from, not ideal.  the ideal part is to use [] in your form.

Comment: hi, Dreaded semicolon thanks for your help. finally i can get value with your jQuery library. it's work. thanks guys for all of you